# Hibernate - unexpected token: in while update

Tags: hibernate

I am getting this error, and I am not able to figure out if there is any error in my query.

Error is:

`ERROR:   line 1:8: unexpected token: in
line 1:8: unexpected token: in`

```
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.updateStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:232).......</code>
```

I am trying to update a table by HQL, following is that code:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("update Order set paymentStatusId = :pid where id = :id");
    query.setParameter("pid", paymentStatusId).setParameter("id", orderId);
query.executeUpdate();
```

My POJO is below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"orders\"")
public class Order implements Serializable{   
    //getters-setters
}
```

Comment: Maybe it mixes up the class Order with the keyword ORDER

Comment: @polypiel: ya, may be. Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Order is a reserved word of HQL. You may try to change the name of the Entity or enclosing the entity name in brackets (no tested):
http://www.javaplex.com/blog/hibernate-how-to-use-databases-reserved-keywords-in-hql-and-pojos/

Comment: Hibernate does not let you put brackets besides entity name in HQL, throws error.